# Calculus of vector functions: arc length and speed

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

[image]

Hi! I am trying to study or a test in my calc3 class by doing some online problems, but I am not quite sure how to solve this one. I thought the correct answer was ((576t^-1/1)+(t^-3/-3)+576t)-(-1/3) but apparently that is incorrect. If someone could kindly help me solve this problem i would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Please add your work to the question so we can see what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** 
$$\mathbf{r}^\prime(t)=\left\langle \dfrac{2\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{t}}, \dfrac{1}{t},12 \right\rangle$$